# gridview setonitemclicklistener only gets values from first item

Tags: android, gridview

i have a gridview with values inside a textview (passID_l). there are different values for each item in the gridview. upon clicking an item, the value of that item will be passed to another fragment.

problem is, whichever item you click, the value that will be passed to the bundle will always be from the 1st item.
e.g. 1st item has value of "1"... 3rd item has value of "3". when I click the 3rd item, "1" will be passed instead of "3"

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id) {
            TextView text = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.passId_l);
            String tEXT = text.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), tEXT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            videoList firstFrag = new videoList(); 
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("key", tEXT);
            firstFrag.setArguments(bundle);
            android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, firstFrag);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit(); 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
        TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.passId_l);
```

instead of

```
        TextView text = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.passId_l);
```

to get TextView from the selected item of GridView